# How can I insulate the exposed interior portion of a garage foundation wall?

Tags: framing

This is a follow-up question to an [earlier post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/287897/35141). I am trying to figure out the best route for a garage renovation. The current exposed bottom plate and walls sit on a foundation wall. There is a 3" gap of exposed foundation at the interior of the framing.

I am going to finish the interior space, probably with a combination of 3/4" birch ply & maybe a T&G accent wall and PVC shoe molding around the exposed foundation. I am planning on insulating the walls and running a mini split or window AC of some kind.

With this in mind, I don't know if I need to align the wall face with the foundation face.

- Do I fur out the gap? Is there a maximum gap you can fur?
- Build an extra 2 1/4" stud wall of some kind?
- Do some kind of boxed in shoe molding around the foundation and keep the existing stud wall as is?
- Something better I didn't mention?

Here is an image showing the existing framing on foundation if this helps.

[image]

Comment: It is very close to being opinion, since it depends if you want a step at the bottom or not.  If the garage is unheated and you want more insulation I would go with a full wall or can use the extra space for ~six inch shelves if no insulation.  Either way keep the step or no step would edit the question on how to do one.

Comment: Floor-to-ceiling 2x4 wall inside the foundation? Horizontal fireblocking every 10 ft bridging the interior and exterior framing becomes important, so aligning the studs makes that easier.

Comment: Please revise your title to ask a clear, specific question so everyone doesn't have to traipse in here to determine whether they may be able to help you. Also, a reference to an earlier post is useless unless you _link to it_.

Comment: This question overlaps your first one, which you've apparently abandoned. Please go back there and address the questions posed in comments.

Comment: @isherwood this post is trying to address new issues that came up from the suggestions of the last post. I felt that post got a good answer so I made a new post instead of editing the previous post. Being new to Stack exchange, it seems impossible to get options on how to solve a problem that has multiple ways of solving it. Being a DIY'er means I don't know what I don't know. If I ask a binary question on how to do "x" but "x" isn't a good way of doing it, I'll get an answer but could be doing something wrong. The stringent format makes it hard to learn, but maybe that is the goal?

Comment: Your problems really aren't related to this site, but basic communication. You aren't making your goals and concerns clear, so it's difficult to answer your questions. My answer below may be way off the mark, but I gleaned what I could from this post and took a guess.

Comment: @isherwood I have taken the tour. The post had comments with answers that I thought were a good solution. Thinking further I realized this new problem (3" gap) came up. But like I said, I don't know what I don't know. Especially when it comes to problems with multiple solutions. This has continued further, with you pointing out the consideration for insulating the block wall (something I had not thought about). I thought this post was pretty straightforward with the 4 options I asked about.

Comment: @crip659 I really don't mind either way, step or no step. I just don't know if there is a best practice for doing something like this.

Comment: For some people a step bugs them, other people see a step to keep small stuff off of the floor, like boots/shoes and lego blocks for after you take the shoes off.

Comment: You can ask about pros/cons. You can present a plan and ask if there are things you've missed. Asking the 3 questions you've asked here, though, is asking for _our_ opinions and _that_ makes it off topic. It may feel restrictive, but in an "either option presented will work" situation, it really does come down to a matter of opinion. You've seen several different opinions here in the comments...

Comment: @FreeMan OK, I guess I just asked for pros/cons and if I was missing anything incorrectly. Because that was what the root of this post is. I am soliciting feedback on the four bullet points. I can edit to reflect such.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to build the wall out to the face of the foundation block. Here's what I did in the same situation.

1. Attach 3/4" or 1" rigid foam to the block on the face and top with compatible panel adhesive. Leave the front panel just a bit taller than the block so it tightens against the floor later for a good seal.
2. Overlay your choice of protective finish. I used OSB, but I kept it up ~1/2" to prevent water absorption. You could use painted wood or vinyl plank or whatever.

   This time, keep the top panel slightly long so things tighten up
   when the front is installed. Attach the front panel through the face and into the wall plate with long screws.
3. Connect the two finish panels with trim nails. This locks the top panel in place, along with friction.

Lap is important with this strategy. Here's how mine looks:

```
|       | <-- stud
|       |
|_______|_____ _
|       |_____| | <-- face board overlaps top board; trim nails here
|_______|_____| | <-- screw here, through top foam board
|           | | |
| block     | | |
|           | | |
|___________|_|_|
```

This all came out super solid and I have no doubt that on -30° F nights it's doing wonders to stop both heat transfer and airflow through my block foundation. Even only being screwed at the top there's no flop at all due to the way things are lapped and cantilevered. Two years later I have no regrets.

I did countersink the long screw heads so they didn't strip or smash things when trying to tighten them, and I also ran a router over the front finish panel to give it a bullnose.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just build a floor to ceiling wall interior to the foundation.

You need a vertical line of fireblocking every 10 ft measured horizontally along the wall, so incorporate that into your design. People commonly use foam panels between the concrete and studs. That's fine, but the foam insulation is relatively expensive.

Alternatively, you can use 2x4 studs with 2x6 bottom plates and a 2x6 stud every 10 ft for fireblocking. This achieves 2x6 wall cavities for cheaper batt insulation. The break even cost between the two details depends on the height of your concrete relative to the rest of the wall. For the upper part of the wall, align your studs with exterior wall studs so that you can bridge the two walls with chunks of drywall for fireblocking.